# How can I add soft credits to a Recurring Contribution Series

Tags: contributions, recurring-contributions, soft-credit

If I sign a donor up for a monthly/Recurring Contribution Series -> then I can go in and add a soft credit to the Contribution.

But I can't add it to the series - so next month - when the next Contribution is generated I don't get any Soft Credits.

Has anyone looked into this? Add fields to Contribution Recurring Series and then code to template those into the Contribution that is generated next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is currently possible, but I've recently been up to my elbows in soft credit customizations.

I think the answer is an extension that checks whether the first gift is soft credited.  If so, it should apply an identical soft credit to succeeding gifts.

I recently released the extension [Soft credit Custom Fields](https://github.com/MegaphoneJon/com.megaphonetech.softcreditcustomfields).  You could use soft credit custom fields to further specify other options.  E.g. only soft credit the first X contributions; if the contribution amount is increased later, does the soft credit increase as well; etc.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to your new ext! Here is where things get complicated for large orgs: multiple soft credits per Contribution PAC series and changes over time: phone banker A recruits initial $20/PAC; phone banker B secures a +$5 increase 6 months later; direct mail dept secures another +$10 in the election year.